# Error(PL,SQL Statement ignored) while running Simple Oracle Stored Procedure in ASP.NET Page

Tags: asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures, ado.net

I am firing the below Oracle Stored Proc from my ASP.NET Page, Defintion below

```
create or replace 
procedure SwapDutyRota(row_id1 in varchar2,row_id2 in varchar2) as
temp_officer varchar2(20);
begin
SELECT duty_officer 
INTO temp_officer
FROM duty_rota WHERE ROWID = row_id1 ;

UPDATE duty_rota 
SET duty_officer = (SELECT duty_officer FROM duty_rota WHERE ROWID = row_id2)
WHERE ROWID = row_id1;

UPDATE duty_rota 
SET duty_officer = temp_officer
WHERE ROWID = row_id2;
END SwapDutyRota;
```

The below snippet of ASP.NET is firing that particular stored proc.

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SwapDutyRota('" + Label1.Text + "','" + DropDownList2.SelectedValue + "')", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conn.Open();
            var a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (a > 0)
            {
                lblSuccess.Visible = true;
                lblSuccess.Text = "Swapped Successfully";
            }

            else
            {
                lblSuccess.Visible = true;
                lblSuccess.Text = "Could not be Swapped";
            }
            conn.Close();
```

When I am running the Stored Proc from Oracle prompt(SQL Developer) it works like a charm but when it is getting fired from above code it is giving below error

> ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00801: internal error [22503]
>   ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Can somebody please help how to get rid of this error? I tried to debug but unable to find any proper way to determine how the whole query is executed and where the stored proc is failing.

Comment: I think the parameters have to be added as OracleParameters, not directly in the query as concatenated strings.

Comment: @Sebas, Thanks for your reply. Can you please guide how could I achieve that? Do you see any problem in my Oracle Stored Proc?

Comment: Check the `OracleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter());` syntax